# How to remove/replace spaces in directory names in Windows

Tags: windows, path

I am trying to access a directory name like

```
C:\Documents and Settings\rasmikanta.g\Desktop\last
```

As there is a space in the path name (i.e. `C:\Documents and Settings`), so I am facing error while accessing this path through hudson server. It won't allow any space.

Is there any way to replace this space with any special character or anything, so that I can access that location?

Answer (score 1):

There are no "special characters" to replace spaces in paths. I don't even know what that would be. If you made some arbitrary character a replacement for spaces, how would you use paths that contained that character?

The standard solution for this is to quote the path string using double-quotes. That ensures that it is seen as a unit and prevents spaces from acting as delimiters. For example:

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\rasmikanta.g\Desktop\last"
```

If your program is truly so broken that it does not support long file names in the year 2013, it's time to unceremoniously throw it away and use something else.

Comment: Hudson is a popular Java CI tool, the problem must be located between the keyboard and the chair.

Comment: Thank's Cody,

By using double quote for the path , it works.